# I want to pass a list of data from a userform to a module?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

Hi I am looking for help with an excel VBA issue. I have created a userform which lets you select from a list of items from one listbox to another. The code for the Userform is as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ColumnName
.AddItem "a"
.AddItem "b"
.AddItem "c"
.AddItem "d"
.AddItem "e"
.AddItem "f"
End With
End Sub
```

Then

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click()
For i = 0 To ColumnName.ListCount - 1
If ColumnName.Selected(i) = True Then selectedColumns.AddItem
ColumnName.List(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Where listbox 1 is ColumnName and Listbox 2 is Selected Columns. I have been trying to pass this list of information to a separate module by first inputting this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
varSelectedColumns = UserForm2.selectedColumns
Unload UserForm2
End Sub
```

Then in the module I want to use this data to make a string so I have

```
Public varSelectedColumns As String, srtQuery As String
sub Skeleton_Query1()

UserForm2.Show

strQuery = "SEL * " & Chr(10) & varSelectedColumns

Range("B2").Value = strQuery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    varSelectedColumns = ""
    With UserForm2.selectedColumns
        If .ListCount = 0 Then
            Beep
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            varSelectedColumns = varSelectedColumns & ", " & .List(i)
        Next i
    End With
    varSelectedColumns = Mid(varSelectedColumns, 3)
    Unload UserForm2
End Sub
```

Although, since `varSelectedColumns` is being assigned a string, you might want to change its name to `strSelectedColumns` to reflect its data type.